# Celery worker failure task requeuing logic (RabbitMQ)

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I have the following setup:

```
celery version = 4.2.1
task_reject_on_worker_lost = True
task_acks_late = True
```

I am trying to get a message to route to "QueueA" initially and if the celery worker that is processing it fails abruptly I would like the message to re-queue to a new queue "QueueB". Is it possible to do this with tweaks to my RabbitMQ queue settings or via celery?

I already have a dead letter exchange properly configured for QueueA which handles this type of routing with, for example, TTL's (i.e. message goes to QueueA sits until TTL then goes to dead letter queue and eventually back to QueueB).

Answer (score 0):

From the [RabbitMQ mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/rabbitmq-users/requeue$20logic%7Csort:date/rabbitmq-users/ed9iHYe-lHQ/muhy2PoGAgAJ)

> Automatic requeueing on channel (and, well, connection) closure always happens to the same queue [1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/rabbitmq-users/requeue$20logic%7Csort:date/rabbitmq-users/ed9iHYe-lHQ/muhy2PoGAgAJ).
>   Such scenario does not lead to dead lettering, do any DLX settings won't have any effect.
>   With quorum queues in 3.8, automatic requeueing could sometimes result in dead lettering because there's an optional
>   redelivery count limit. That would be close to what you are looking for. Since quorum queues are not a feature available in RabbitMQ 3.7, neither is this feature.
>   3.8.0 is at beta.3 at the moment [2] and will ship in mid-2019.
>   1. https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html
>   2. https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/releases/tag/v3.8.0-beta.3
>   The redelivery limit is documented here(https://next.rabbitmq.com/quorum-queues.html)